# Basis of linear maps $\mathbb{Z}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}^m$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Given a linear map $\mathbb{Z}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}^m$, how can we find a basis for the image?

For example, if $\phi: \mathbb{Z}^4 \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}^2$, given by $(z_1...z_4) \rightarrow (2z_1 + z_3 - 5z_4, 2z_2 + z_3 + z_4)$, how can we find basis of its image?

I thought to use regular row reduction, but then realized this wouldn't work because how do we get leading $1$'s (since $Z$ is not a field)?

Comment: You can still do row reduction, but indeed you cannot always divide by things to get leading one's. When working with $\mathbb Z^n$ instead of a vector space, you can have torsion in the cokernel.

Comment: @Dave I see. So how do you do row reduction then? I don't know too much about torsion.

Comment: Proceed over $\mathbb{Q}$ instead of $\mathbb{Z}$ since it is a field. Then clear denominators to place the result back in $\mathbb{Z}$. This works because you have found the common multiple first rather than clearing denominators.

Comment: I suggest using Smith Normal Form

Comment: @EricNathanStucky he's looking for the image which is spanned by $(2,0,1,-5)$ and $(0,2,1,1)$. This is actually in row reduced form already using the method I provided.

Comment: @EricNathanStucky if you want the column space you just do row reduction on the transpose. I posted an answer.

Comment: The process in your answer is valid, but I still do not agree that it agrees with the method you described in your first comment. In any case, since your intended meaning is now clearer, I'm deleting my previous comments for brevity's sake.

Answer (score 3):

For the example, you can sort of guess the answer: a basis is $(2,0)$ and $(1,1)$. Clearly these are in the image and linearly independent. There can't be more basis elements because the rank of the image is at most $2$; this is not enough to show they span, but here you can simply note that
$$(2z_1 + z_3 - 5z_4, 2z_2 + z_3 + z_4) = [2z_2+z_3+z_4](1,1) + [z_1-z_2-3z_4](2,0).$$
(The "good luck" here is that the second coordinate has a $1$ in one basis element and a $0$ in the other, so we can set the second coordinate and then fix the first.)

---

However, in general Smith Normal Form indeed provides the canonical answer. The theory needed is that for any matrix $A$ of dimensions $p\times q$ over $\mathbb{Z}$, then there is a decomposition $A=PDQ$ into two matrices $P$ and $Q$ which are invertible over $\mathbb{Z}$ (that is, their determinants are $\pm 1$) and a diagonal matrix $D=(d_1,\dots, d_{\min(p,q)})$ of dimension $p\times q$ such that $d_i|d_j$ for all $i<j$.

How does this help? Well, first note $\text{im}(D)$ is very easy to calculate: it is simply $d_1\mathbb{Z} \times\cdots\times d_{\min(p,q)}\mathbb{Z}$. And then the invertibility of $P$ and $Q$ give us that $\text{im}(A)=P\cdot\text{im}(D)$, because $Ax=P\cdot D(Qx)$.

So the remaining difficulty is to calculate these magic matrices. There are a couple ways to do this.

- If you have an explicit example that you want to work with, then there exist "Gaussian-elimination-like" algorithms; [Wikipedia has one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith_normal_form#Algorithm), and there are no shortage of Google results if you find that one hard to read. If you're not so concerned with the details, there are a number of of Smith normal form calculators online as well; [here's one](http://www.numbertheory.org/php/smith.html) I found and used to check my guess above.
- There is a good reason why the algorithm seems like Gaussian elimination: note that if we were working over $\Bbb{Q}$ instead of $\Bbb{Z}$, then the $LDU$-decomposition suffices. Thus the Smith normal form can be understood as simply a way to encode (invertible) *row and column* operations— indeed, $P$ controls the row operations, and $Q$ the column operations. So if you can find a sequence of operations that turns $A$ into an appropriate diagonal $D$, then you can encode that into a $P$ and hence an image computation.

The second idea is of course more flexible, so can be more useful for doing many computations at once (e.g. if you had an $n\times n$ matrix for each $n$). It's worth noting that $P$ and $Q$ are not unique for a given $A$, so two people may arrive at different bases in this way.

Comment: If you understand what's going on here you might first object that $\text{im}(A)=P\cdot\text{im}(D)$ does not a priori answer your question, since you obviously already knew a *spanning* set for $\text{im}(A)$. But in fact this equation gives a basis: why?

Comment: I included some details on a possible implementation in my *answer*.  Am I simply re-doing existing Smith Normal Form implementations?

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to find a $\mathbb Z$-basis $(v_1,\ldots,v_k)$ for the *kernel* of $\phi$.  Then one completes this basis to a $\mathbb Z$-basis $(v_1,\ldots,v_k, v_{k+1},\ldots, v_n)$ of $\mathbb Z^n$.  Then the images $\phi(v_{k+1}),\ldots,\phi(v_n)$ form a $\mathbb Z$-basis for the image of $\phi$.

One practical idea would be to use the fact that a bunch of vectors in a lattice that are an $\mathbb R$-basis will also be a $\mathbb Z$-basis if and only if the volume of the parallelepided spanned by the vectors is the smallest possible.  Thus, one could construct a basis inductively on the dimension $n$ of the source $\mathbb Z^n=\text{Span}(e_1,\ldots,e_n)$ as follows.  Suppose we already found a $\mathbb Z$-basis consisting of $k$ vectors $(v_1,\ldots,v_k)$.  Now we go on to the next vector $e_\ell^{\phantom I}$ in the basis for $\mathbb Z$, which may be $e_{k+1}$ or have larger index if linear dependencies were found earlier.  Suppose $e_\ell^{\phantom I}$ is $\mathbb R$-independent of the $\mathbb R$-span of $(v_1,\ldots,v_k)$ (this can easily be checked by row reduction, or by computing the determinants of the appropriate minors).  Then we adjoin $e_\ell^{\phantom I}$ to the $\mathbb Z$-basis, and go on to $e_{\ell+1}$.  If $e_\ell^{\phantom I}$ is in the $\mathbb R$-span, this is the main step of the procedure.

In this case, we express $e_\ell^{\phantom I}$ as a linear combination of $(v_1,\ldots,v_k)$, and then subtract off *integer multiples* of the vectors $v_1,\ldots,v_k$ to make sure that all the coefficients are *at most* $\frac12$ in absolute value.  Then the point is the replacement of the appropriate $v_i$ by $e_\ell^{\phantom I}$ *decreases the $k$-dimensional volume of the parallelepiped by at least a factor of $2$*.  If the discarded vector $v_i$ is not in the $\mathbb Z$-span of the new improved basis, we now express $v_i$ as a linear combination with coefficients at most $\frac12$ in absolute value, and so on until we obtain a $\mathbb Z$-basis.  The convergence is exponential and therefore should be computationally efficient if such a scheme is implemented.

Comment: Does the same question not arise? Namely, how to find a basis for the kernel? Since this also seems to require row reduction?

Comment: @algebroo To me it seems like a better idea because calculating the kernel looks more easily like imposing constraints on the z's, and from that, calculating a basis seems easier. But Eric's answer does seem more reliable

Comment: To answer your question on my answer: yes, I think the correct version of your idea is an implementation of SNF. Subtracting off integer multiples of the existing basis vectors is an invertible column operation, and the requirement that volume is reduced should filter into the divisibility requirement on the diagonal matrix. I'm fairly confident you could fiddle this into a proof along the lines of "Suppose $A=PDQ$ and the columns of $A$ are $v_i$. Now add to $A$ a new column $e_\ell=\sum c_iv_i$ for rational $c_i$. The SNF changes as follows..."

Answer (score 0):

We can use row reduction on the matrix $$\begin{bmatrix}2&0\\0&2\\1&1\\1&-5\end{bmatrix}$$ So letting $r_1,r_2,r_3$ and $r_4$ be the rows of the matrix we see that $r_2=r_1-2r_3$ and $r_4=r_3-3r_2$ so those rows can be zeroed out meaning the row reduced form is \begin{bmatrix}1&1\\0&2\\0&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix} and so $(1,1)$ and $(0,2)$ are a basis. Note that we didn't get a $1$ in the last pivot which you'd expect if we were working over a field but otherwise the process is identical.

Comment: What is the definition of "row reduced"? I'm just not sure why we can conclude that (i) this is row reduced, since we don't have leading 1's and 0's only (which is the usual definition), and (ii) why the form of this implies that (1,1) and (0,2) is a basis.

Comment: @algebroo it's not in row reduced echelon form but it's in echelon form. There is no requirement that the leading entry be $1$. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_echelon_form